# __doPostBack and hit function

Tags: javascript, dopostback

I want my javascript to fire the postback event.  I have put the javascript call in the onClientClick:

```
<asp:Button ID="submit_btn" runat="server" 
            OnClientClick="javascript:doSubmit();" Text="Update" Width="75px" 
            Height="26px" PostBackUrl="#"  />
```

I am verifying some values and then submitting:

```
        __doPostBack('submit_btn', '');
```

The problem is that the 'click event submit_btn_Click is not being hit.  I thought this would be the case!  Is this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<asp:Button>` will always generate a post-back event, and flow into your `Page_OnLoad()` and other initialization events. You won't need to specifically call the JavaScript method  `__doPostBack()`.

Comment: Ok, so is there a way to get the 'click' event for the submit_btn to fire without putting it in the OnClick event for the button?